# Textmate now requires my password?

Tags: php, mysql, textmate, nano

I'm following Kevin Skoglund's "Php using MySQL" tutorials on lynda.com. In the installation he uses sudo a lot to configure stuff and open files. All of this is on the terminal for Macintosh computers. He starts the apache server using `sudo apachectl start` or `restart`. He also opens many pages with the nano text editor(which is used in the terminal) and he uses `sudo` before the majority of the commands. The pages he goes into are things like php.ini.

Before I started his course, I installed php and MySQL in a different way, that caused some problems with the 'socket'(I'm not too familiar with what a socket is). So that's why I had to go to the installation chapter to install everything the sudo way(I'm aware that sudo is more dangerous than smoking at a petrol station).

So now when I go to textmate, it constantly requires my user password to save files and the files in my project drawer glow red. Also, even if I do type my password, it makes the sound that means "YOU CAN NOT DO THIS!". Could you please tell me how to make everything stop requiring passwords? PLEASE HELP! Thanks.

Edit: Ok, when I use `ls -la` in my php folder, the files come up with "rw-r--r--". Anyone know how to change the permissions?

Comment: I suggest you read up on UNIX file ownership and permissions.

Comment: Could you elaborate, please?

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=UNIX+file+ownership+and+permissions